# How to reorder a dataframe based on a list? pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, reorderlist

I have a df and I want to reorder it based on athe list as shown using Python:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Country':["AU","DE","UR","US","GB","SG","KR","JP","CN"],'Stage #': [3,2,6,6,3,2,5,1,1],'Amount':[4530,7668,5975,3568,2349,6776,3046,1111,4852]})
```

df

```
list=["US","CN","GB","AU","JP","KR","UR","DE","SG"]
```

How can I do that? Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html)

```
list_ = ["US","CN","GB","AU","JP","KR","UR","DE","SG"]

df['Country'] = pd.Categorical(df.Country, categories = list_, ordered = True)
df.sort_values(by='Country')
```

Also, do not name your variable `list` because that would override the built-in `list` command

Comment: How would you do the same as above, but if there were 2 lists?